# Why is my SignalR-Application is so slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following setup:

- Jquery v2.2.4 (Client)
- SignalR v2.3.0 (Server)
- ASP.NET C# MVC 4

I am now trying to use SignalR for Data-Transportation for huge data like ~3500-~5000 Key-Value-Pairs. These Pairs consists of an ID as Key and a long name as value.

I am sending a request from my JS-Client to the Server and the Server promptly answers with the result but the client takes minute after minute to download the data. After 5 minutes the client has downloaded 700 bytes (!) from the server.

This is running on localhost with an SSD and an i5 as CPU so it should run faster.

Client code:

```
var selectedMarketID = GlobalVariables._currentMarketID;
var _dict = {
    "selectedMarketID": selectedMarketID
};
var dict = JSON.stringify(_dict);
GlobalVariables._globalBroadcastStation.server.sendUserAvailableOrderStrings(dict);
```

The Server code:

```
public void SendUserAvailableOrderStrings(string JSONData)
{
var userData = GetData();
Clients.Caller.messageReturn("availableOrderStrings", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData));
}
```

SignalR Startup Class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Classes.SignalR.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication1.Classes.SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 500;
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

The function `Clients.Caller.messageReturn` just displays the output to the user in this case. So there is no further calculation there.

A data split for continuos data transfer to the user is not possible as the user can easily change a setting in the frontend which will result in a new request to the server for `SendUserAvailableOrderStrings`.

Why is the SignalR-Connection so slow?

Comment: the old SignalR was also slow for me. The new ASP.net Core version is faster